# How to send a refresh if the waiting time is exceeded while running a loop?

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, rselenium

I have been encountering some timeout errors that stop my loop. I first tried to simply increase the waiting time with this commands:

```
remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(milliseconds = 100000)
remDr$setTimeout(type = "page load", milliseconds = 100000)
```

However, I noticed that simply increasing the waiting time do not solve the issue because the website simple gets frozen sometimes, and the only way to fix it is by refreshing. So, I was wondering if there is a way to refresh the browser if the waiting time is exceeded?

Comment: @Psidom, I'm aware of that function. But what I need is to send a refresh when an error has happened while running a loop.

Comment: i don't have enough exp in r, but in java, i can do this in another way....i can share this with u if u can convert this to r.

Answer (score 1):

I found that there is a command to read the HTML code, and also to catch the errors. This is working for me:

```
  while(class(try(remDr$getPageSource(header = TRUE), silent = TRUE))=="try-error"){try(remDr$refresh(), silent = TRUE)}
```

It is worth to point out, that in order for this to work it is necessary to increase the timeout of page loading. This is what is working for me:

```
remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(milliseconds = 10000)
remDr$setTimeout(type = "page load", milliseconds = 100000)
```